# jQuery validate only if a specific radio button is selected

Tags: jquery

I got stuck at a particular situation

I have 2 radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" value="YES" id="sub" name="sub">Yes
<input type="radio" value="NO" id="sub" name="sub">No
```

When, Yes is selected, I need to validated 1 text-field

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
```

I am using jQuery validation plug-in

Please help me with this, Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you should never have 2 elements with the same id.

Comment: @Abdullah: thanks for drawing my attention to it

Comment: @Abdullah Thanks that was the reason the Answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set up dependency validation as seen here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

```
$('#myForm').validate(rules: {
   price: { 
     required: '#sub[value="YES"]:checked'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Vadmin, can you please have a look at this related question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758931

Comment: Why `#yes:checked` ?  Do you assume that the OP wrote `id='yes'` instead of `id='sub'` ?