# jQuery validate - User must select YES radio (not no) in order to conitnue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I would like to set up a jQuery validate rule to require that YES (not no) be checked in order for the form to validate/submit. User must accept terms. If the user selects no they will get the error msg and the form will not validate. What is the correct way to accomplish this using jquery validate plugin?

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="terms" id="terms1" value="Yes!" class="required" title="Must accept terms to continue" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="terms" id="terms2" value="No" class="required" title="Must accept terms to continue" /> No
</form>

$("#myForm").validate({ 

/*
Insert your awesome jquery validation code here. Free beer to whoever answers the question!
*/

});
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ThcS8/1/

Kudos to anyone who can provide a solution or even better an example! Vote this up if you are looking for the same solution so it gets attention. Thanks all!

Please vote for your favorite solution!

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't use the same id for both radio buttons. Ids should be unique.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535187/jquery-validate-form-with-multiple-checkboxes-at-least-one-must-be-checked ?

Comment: Any reason why you need to have 2 radio buttons for both Yes and No rather than just a checkbox "I agree"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also had this problem, and tried various things including the solutions mentioned above. In the end I wrote a custom validator method to check for a required value in a radio button:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredRadioValue", function(value, element, params) { 
    var selectedValue = $('input:radio[name=' + element.name + ']:checked').val(); 
    return (typeof(params) == 'array') ? (params.indexOf(selectedValue) != -1) : selectedValue == params;
}, "You must select the required option.");
```

The method is used e.g.

```
signedcif: { requiredRadioValue: 'yes' }
```

the allowed options can be an array or single value.

Hope this helps, I was hoping this wasn't the most straight-forward way to do this, so any alternatives gratefully received!

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the required from the no input radio and then simply do

```
$("form").validate();
```

this initializes the jquery validation. It will see the yes is required to be selected and won't let the form submit until it is.

Comment: Thanks Keith but then the issue is that there is no error message telling the user why the form is not submitting.

Comment: This should force jquery validate to pop up a red "This field is required" message below that radio button when they click submit. You can also define your own custom messages using jquery validate. See this example: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options scroll down until you get the the "messages" section.

Comment: Thanks Keith I am using jQuery validate, and my form does require either yes or no be selected, however I want it to only submit if the user selects yes. If the users selects the no radio I want them to see an error msg.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but this method just plain doesn't work for me -- it makes it so both the "yes" and the "no" radio buttons can be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

change the value from true and false to 1 and 0 respectively. and add rule
for

```
$('form').validate({
rules:{
    terms: {min:1}
},
messages:{
    terms: {min:'you must accept terms to move on.'}
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Funky! Could you go into more detail showing me how you would do this?

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding that rule and it now displays the error message whether I select Yes or No. Thoughts?

Comment: forget that rule. try adding validate="required:true" to yes radio element.

Comment: and remove class="required" from no radio element

Comment: Thanks Funky, still no luck. Have a look at this code and edit as you see fit. http://jsfiddle.net/ThcS8/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the checkbox has the class 'required' and has the name 'agreeForm', here is something that could work:

```
   jQuery("#regForm").validate({
      debug: true,
      rules: {
        agreeForm: "required",
      },
      messages: {
        agreeForm: "Please accept our Terms and Conditions.",
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Demitry, I will have to try this out.