# jQuery validate only if a specific radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, radio-button, validation

this is my first post here and I'm super amateur at all of this, so please bear with me.
I have already looked at: [jQuery validate only if a specific radio button is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676991/jquery-validate-only-if-a-specific-radio-button-is-selected) and many of the posts linked by people replying to these posts. I feel like I have everything right, but it's just not working.

I have a basic contact form that will allow users to either give feedback, request info, or request services. I would like to have the 'Address' field be required only if there is going to be a Service Order/Request. Right now there is nothing I can figure out to make 'Address' required short of replacing the conditional statement 'required: "ConReas_1:checked"' with 'required: true'. The id for that specific radio button is 'ConReas_1'

The HTML:

```
...<td><label for="Address">Address: </label> 
    <input name="Address" type="text" id="Address" value="Street Address Including Apt. # if applicable." /></td>...

      ...<table width="600">
        <tr><td colspan="2"><label id="CRlabel">Reason for contact:</label></td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="189"><label>
            <input type="radio" name="ConReas" value="InfoReq" id="ConReas_0" onclick="OrderYN()"/>
            Request Info</label></td><td width="399"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="radio" name="ConReas" value="ServReq" id="ConReas_1" onclick="OrderYN()" />
            Order / Request Services</label></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="radio" name="ConReas" value="WebFB" id="ConReas_2" onclick="OrderYN()" />
            Website Feedback</label></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input type="radio" name="ConReas" value="GenFB" id="ConReas_3" onclick="OrderYN()" />
            General Feedback</label></td><td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>...
```

The Javascript:

```
//Custom rules for form validation
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please enter your correct info.");

//Form Validation
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact").validate({
    rules: {
        Fname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            notEqual: "First Name"
        },
        Lname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            notEqual: "Last Name"
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            notEqual: "name@example.com"
        },
        EmConf: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#Email",
            notEqual: "name@example.com"
        },
        ConReas: {
            required: true
        },
        Comment: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 20,
            notEqual: "Enter your comment, feedback, or question here."
        },
        Address:{
            required: "#ConReas_1:checked",
        },
        City:{
            required: true,
            notEqual: "City"
        },
        State:{
            required: true,
        },
        Zip:{
            required: true,
            notEqual: "XXXXX"
        }
    },debug:true,
    messages: {
        EmConf: {
            equalTo: "Both Email fields must match."
        },
        ConReas: {
            required: "You must select a contact reason."
        },
        Comment: {
            notEqual: "Please enter your comment, feedback or question below."
        },
        State: {
            required: "Please select your state."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
        if ( element.attr("name") == "ConReas" ) 
            error.insertAfter("#CRlabel");
        else if (element.attr("name") == "Comment" )
            error.insertAfter("#cmtlbl");
        else
            error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
$("#ConReas_01").click(function() {
    $("#Address").valid();
});
$("#ConReas_1").click(function() {
    $("#Address").valid();
});
$("#ConReas_2").click(function() {
    $("#Address").valid();
});
$("#ConReas_3").click(function() {
    $("#Address").valid();
});
});
```

Thanks in advance to any help provided. These forums have been a God-send in teaching myself web design.

Comment: Hi. I think you're missing a `#` char (id selector). Rule should be `required: "#ConReas_1:checked"`